# How to pass array of object in java-script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

in google map I try to show my patient location I can get my patient location by this function but i don't know how to link it to next function for showing my patient in google map.

```
 function getPoints() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Patient.asmx/GetPatient",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var Patientlocation = response.d;
            $.each(Patientlocation, function (index, Patientlocation) {
                $('#output').append('new google.maps.LatLng(' + Patientlocation.lat + ' ' + Patientlocation.lng + ')<br/>');
            });
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

this is default google map i have to pass map object from above function to it 
could you please help

```
<script>

    // This example requires the Visualization library. Include the libraries=visualization
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=visualization">

    var map, heatmap;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: { lat: 34.0475, lng: -118.434 },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        });

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: getPoints(),
            map: map
        });
    }

    function toggleHeatmap() {
        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
    }

    function changeGradient() {
        var gradient = [
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
      'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
      'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
      'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
      'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
    ]
        heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
    }

    function changeRadius() {
        heatmap.set('radius', heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20);
    }

    function changeOpacity() {
        heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
    }

    // Heatmap data: 500 Points
    function getPoints1() {
        return [
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.0482551, -118.434),
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.0442551, -118.444),
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.0422551, -118.454),
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.0402551, -118.464),
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.0502551, -118.474),
      new google.maps.LatLng(34.0522551, -118.484)
    ];
    }
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=visualization&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

here is JsonFile

```
<ArrayOfPatientLocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<PatientLocation>
 <lat>34.0369842</lat>
 <lng>-118.23060729999997</lng>
</PatientLocation>
<PatientLocation>
 <lat>34.0369842</lat>
 <lng>-118.22060729999997</lng>
</PatientLocation>
<PatientLocation>
 <lat>34.0369842</lat>
 <lng>-118.24060729999997</lng>
</PatientLocation>
<PatientLocation>
 <lat>34.0369842</lat>
 <lng>-118.24060729999997</lng>
</PatientLocation>
</ArrayOfPatientLocation>
```

Comment: assign the result to a global var  and the use this var where you need

Comment: No! Do not use a global variable, _especially_ not to handle data returned from AJAX requests! You will have endless headaches and timing issues.

Comment: Did my answer resolve the problem?

Comment: Thanks for help Michael but it didn't work

Comment: If you clarify the problem (and explain how my solution failed to solve it), I can try to help.

Comment: I just noticed that you edited your question to add your "JSON" file. However, that's actually XML, not JSON. Have you inspected the AJAX response to ensure that it's actually converting to an array of JS objects, and not remaining a giant string of XML?

Comment: yes when i run the first part I get read data and show in page the missing part is we need to make array of map object and then pass it to please look at getpoint1()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Google Maps API and I haven't tested this, but I think something like this should work.

First, modify your initMap function to accept an array of patient location objects, rather than calling a function to return a hard-coded list:

```
// modify initMap to accept an array of location objects
function initMap(patientLocations) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: { lat: 34.0475, lng: -118.434 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });

    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: patientLocations,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Then modify your `getPoints` ajax function to map the list of locations returned from the API to google maps location objects and pass that to `initMap`

```
function getPoints() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Patient.asmx/GetPatient",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var patientlocations = response.d;
            // transform array of JSON objects into google maps location objects
            patientlocations = $.map(Patientlocations, function(patentLocation) {
                return new google.maps.LatLng(patentLocation.lat, patentLocation.lng);
            });

            // pass modified locations into initMap()
            initMap(patientLocations);
        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });
}
```